# Split string (path of Uri) based on "/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

Wonder if someone could point me in the right direction. What I'd like to achieve is to split a string based upon it having a '/' in it. For example if I had: www.site.com/course/123456/216 in code (c#) I'd like to be able to split the string in code so that 123456 could be assigned to variable param1 and 216 be assigned to param2 (course is the 'friendly' name of the page). If I was to add a third '/' on the string I'd like this to become param3, etc, etc.

Ideally I'd like to be able to put this code somewhere that I could include it on whichever usercontrols I'd need it to work.

Comment: It's unconventional, but certainly doable.  You can get the raw URL (and all sorts of information about it) from the `Request` object.  At that point you have a string which you can split by "/" and do whatever you like with it.

Comment: Those aren't query strings... those are subdirectories. Also why do you want useless variables? Use arrays.

Comment: The example you gave (`www.site.com/course/123456/216`) is a URL, not a query string (`www.site.com/course?param1=123456&param2=216`).

Comment: What's wrong with the split function?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: They're not subdirectories either :)  The whole thing is a "resource identifier."

Comment: @David They used to be subdirectories until .htaccess.

Comment: Query string references removed from question (it looks like "path of Uri" is better) - feel free to edit/revert. Thank you notes removed (please discuss it on META if you disagree - [Should thank you be removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) ).

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: No, they were never subdirectories.  HTTP is not a file system.  And `.htaccess` has very little to do with C# and ASP.NET (as referenced in this question).  Most web servers will, by default, map requests to the file system.  But that doesn't make the request a directory.

Comment: @David It doesn't. But you understood what I meant.#

Answer (score 27):

[Uri.Segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.segments?view=netframework-4.8) maybe what you are looking for:

```
new Uri("http://www.contoso.com/foo/bar/index.htm#search").Segments
```

Results in `[ "/", "foo/", "bar/", "index.html" ]`

Comment: You could use segments if you are always going to split on /.  Like `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Select(x=>x.TrimEnd('/')).Skip(2).ToArray()`

Comment: Hi folks, just to let you know that I've been dragged onto another project so I'll be trying the suggestions over the next couple of days.  Cheers folks

Comment: The link provided redirect to uri fragment, not segments

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use split?

```
var valueArray = "www.site.com/course/123456/216".Split('/');
```

The array will have the entire string broken up

index 0 would be "www.site.com" and so forth.

Comment: Because that's not valid C#.

Comment: are you talking about the case?

Comment: I just tested it and, at least after the last edition by Javalsu, it is perfectly valid.

Comment: given url of `server/func2/SubFunc2`

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }. `string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;`

Answer (score 2):

Well, making the **assumption** that the values would **not** have `/` in them:

```
var splitVals = queryString.Split('/');
var vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 2; i <= splitVals.Count; i++)
{
    vals.Add(string.Format("param{0}", i), vals[i]);
}
```

That would get you started. Now, if you're looking to set them to real variables then you'd need to do some casting and leverage reflection, but your question isn't near clear enough to make any real assumptions there.

## EDIT

To make this code reusable I would build an extension method:

```
namespace System
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> SplitQueryString(this string queryString)
        {
            var splitVals = queryString.Split('/');
            var vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for (int i = 2; i <= splitVals.Count; i++)
            {
                vals.Add(string.Format("param{0}", i), vals[i]);
            }

            return vals;
        }
    }
}
```

because then you could do this:

```
var vals = queryString.SplitQueryString();
```

Comment: Small typo: you did parm instead of param.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all the responses!

I was thinking about using the split function but I wasn't sure if there was some other (better) way of achieving what I was after.

I'll have a bash and let you all know how I got on. Also as a sub point what would be the best way of making this chunk of code reusable?

Thanks again for all your time.

Craig

Comment: given url of `server/func2/SubFunc2`

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }. `string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;`

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/')
```

Comment: Accessible from just about everywhere, including static classes, filters, etc.

Comment: That will put your friendly name (course) in element 0, 123456 in element 1, 216 in element 2, and your optional parameter in element 3 if it exists.  I can show you how to remove the first one, but the easiest way to do is something like: `var x=new List<string>(above); x.RemoveAt(0);` or `var x=new Queue<string>(above); x.Dequeue();`

Comment: If you can use LINQ then the following would be even shorter: `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Skip(1).ToArray()`

Comment: Sorry, forgot the split in there `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Skip(1).ToArray()`. You could also use the segments as well, like `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Select(x=>x.TrimEnd('/')).Skip(2).ToAr‌​ray()`

Comment: given url of `server/func2/SubFunc2`

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }. `string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;`

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

`string QueryString = "1234/567/890";
string[] QueryArray = QueryString.Split('/');`

Now `QueryArray[0] = 1234`, `QueryArray[1] = 567`, `QueryArray[2] = 890`,

Comment: `(char)47` seems like overkill. Why not just `'/'`?

Comment: As a note the URLs that I currently have are something like www.site.com?crseidcode=123456&crseprofile=123 and I'm looking for a way to tidy up this URL (it could comprise of loads of parameters). The parameters being passed are always integers.

Comment: Really, that is what query strings are for. You could separate them as you are suggesting, but I think you might run the risk of making thinks less readable/understandable, for little benefit. If you are passing a lot of parameters/data though, you should consider using a `POST` request instead of passing stuff via the querystring. I understand this might not be possible though, dependant on your situation.

Comment: given url of `server/func2/SubFunc2`

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }. `string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;`

Answer (score 1):

url: `server/func2/SubFunc2`

// Get path components. Trailing separators. Returns { "/", "func2/", "sunFunc2" }.
`string[] pathsegments = myUri.Segments;`